# Why is this lua script unable to open a Windows subdirectory?

Tags: windows, scripting, lua, vlc

I'm trying to determine if one of several directories are present from within a lua script. It works on OSX, but not on Windows (linux is currently untested, but I expect that one to work).  When the following code runs, I get an error:

**failed with this C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\: No such file or directory**

I can confirm that that directory exists. I've escaped the slashes, I'm not sure what else could be the issue.

```
local oses = { "/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/playlist/"; "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\lua\\playlist\\"; "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\lua\\playlist\\"; "/usr/lib/vlc/lua/playlist" }

-- Determine which OS this is (and where to find share/lua).
local f,err = io.open( oses[1], "r")
if not err then
    opsys = "OSX"
    scriptpath = oses[1] .. script
    f:close()
else
    f,err = io.open( oses[2], "r")
    if not err then
        opsys = "Win32"
        scriptpath = oses[2] .. script
        f:close()
    else
        f,err = io.open( oses[3], "r")
        vlc.msg.dbg( dhead .. 'failed with this ' .. err .. dtail ) 
        if not err then
            opsys = "Win64"
            scriptpath = oses[3] .. script
            f:close()
        else
            f,err = io.open( oses[4], "r")
            if not err then
                opsys = "Linux/Unix"
                scriptpath = oses[4] .. script
                f:close()
            else
                return false
            end
        end
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *file* "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\playlist\" does not exist. If you were to remove the trailing slash, you'd be trying to open a directory and probably get a permissions error. It's not going to work either way. If you're going to use this method of determining OS, you should be trying to open *files*.

For instance, build your script path, try to open that file, and use *that* to determine pass/fail.

Side note, the structure of your code could be vastly improved. Any time you have a bunch of duplicate code that differs by an index, you should be using a loop. For instance, we can replace your code with this:

```
local oses = {
    ["OSX"]        = "/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/playlist/",
    ["Win32"]      = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\lua\\playlist\\",
    ["Win64"]      = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\lua\\playlist\\",
    ["Linux/Unix"] = "/usr/lib/vlc/lua/playlist",
}
for osname, directory in pairs(oses) do
    local scriptpath = directory..script
    local f,err = io.open( scriptpath, "r")
    if not err then
        f:close()
        return scriptpath, osname
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you with the for the code improvements. I will switch to opening the script's own file, rather than the directory, and I'll do the structure improvements too. Note though that on unix-like OSs it seems to allow you to open a directory and only fails if it's non-existent.

Comment: I'm accepting this. It's definitely the directory vs. file thing that caused the initial problem. And the structure help was also nice... still learning. There are a few other places where I can use loops too that I need to go back and make better now that they're working. Thank you very much.

Comment: For Unix-like OSes directories **are** files (like many other things, like devices, pipes, etc.). So you can open them and read them to discover their content. Instead on Windows directories and regular files are completely different beasts.