# Permission denied in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lua

I have the following Lua code:

```
local f = io.popen("/home/mohammad/LUA", "r")
if f then
    print(f:read("*a"))
else
    print("failed to read")
end
```

When I execute it in Ubuntu I get an error:

```
mohammad@ubuntu:~$ lua LUA/project.lua
sh: 1: /home/mohammad/LUA: Permission denied
```

This is the file permission:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mohammad mohammad 1185 Feb  3 01:56 LUA/project.lua*
```

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: check `/home/mohammad/LUA` permission

Comment: try `sudo lua LUA/project.lua` instead

Comment: its permission is drwxrwxrwx too
and I do it with sudo and its error is 
    sh: 1: /home/mohammad/LUA: Permission denied  
again

Answer (score 3):

You are doing

```
lua LUA/project.lua
```

If `project.lua` is in `/home/mohammad/LUA` then with

```
io.popen("/home/mohammad/LUA", "r")
```

you are attempting to *popen* (pipe-open) the folder. But popen docs in [Lua ref manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.popen) say

> Starts program prog in a separated process and returns a file handle
>   that you can use to read data from this program

A folder is not a process so this won't work.

If you meant to use io.open, the call will succeed if folder exists, and the return will be non-nil on Linux (some differences between Linux and Windows in [Why is this lua script unable to open a Windows subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145370/why-is-this-lua-script-unable-to-open-a-windows-subdirectory)).